# useState passed from parent to child and used in child doesn't trigger the re-render of the child

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering, next.js, use-state

So, I guess the parent doesn't re-render the child component when the useState is updated.
But the component should re-render automatically when using useState right ?
Or I am missing something...

**index.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

import Clicking from "./clicking";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const parentBtn = useRef(null);

  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Clicks: ", clicks);

    if (null !== parentBtn.current) {
      parentBtn.current.addEventListener("click", () => setClicks(clicks + 1));
    }
  }, [clicks]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Clicks number : {clicks}</p>
      <Clicking clicks={clicks} setClicks={setClicks} />
      <button ref={parentBtn}>Parent button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**clicking.js**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Clicking = ({ clicks, setClicks }) => {
  const childBtn = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    childBtn.current.addEventListener("click", () => setClicks(clicks + 1));
  }, []);

  return <button ref={childBtn}>Child button</button>;
};

export default Clicking;
```

Does anyone know how to fix that ?

Here a codesandbox of the case : https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-sun-9993d

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `useEffect` only runs once, and therefore only receives the initial value of `clicks`.
What you need to do is stop passing the `clicks` value to the child and simply get the state value from the `setClicks` function, as your updates depends on the previous state value anyway.

You should also pass `setClicks` as a dependency to `useEffect`, even though it is not technically mandatory in this case as the function is memoized and therefore will never change, but it's a best practice and you will avoid bugs in the future if you do it.

However the `useEffect` in the child is useless in your case anyway and you would be better off simply passing a `onClick` prop to the child that will trigger the parent's function to update the counter when the button is clicked.
The same thing is true for the parent though, and you could simply use the `onClick` prop instead of using `useRef` and end up with this much simpler code:

index.js

```js
import { useState } from "react";

import Clicking from "./clicking";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0);

  const updateClicksCounter = () => {
    setClicks(clicks => clicks + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Clicks number : {clicks}</p>
      <Clicking onClick={updateClicksCounter} />
      <button onClick={updateClicksCounter}>Parent button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

clicking.js

```js
const Clicking = ({ onClick }) => {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Child button</button>;
};

export default Clicking;
```

Comment: Alright, thanks @Valentin , so now it updates properly the `clicks` var, but If I want to display the `clicks` var in the child, how can I get the updated state ?
For now if I pass `clicks` to the child and console.log it, it always displays the initial value of it.

Comment: @Maël if you pass it as props, you can simply display it in the return with `{clicks}`. If you want to use the value in a `useEffect` you need to pass it as a parameter so it will run every time the parameter updates `useEffect(() => { console.log("clicks", clicks) }, [clicks])`

Comment: Ok, I was trying to use it outside of useEffect, so it wasn't sync with react. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, in the child where I use the `setClicks`

I replaced

```
setClicks(clicks + 1)
```

by

```
setClicks(val => val + 1)
```

And it works.
Maybe if someone has an explanation regarding the react lifecycle or else ?

Comment: Instead of passing the stae and setState to the child. Bubble up the onClick event to the parent

Comment: I have created a sample code - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-lamarr-fj24m?file=/pages/index.js